# How do I fetch all pages of the menu with zomato API?

Tags: api, zomato-api

I am using the Zomato API in my application . I queried restaurants in an area with the the following

https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=RESID

and I get a JSON response of restaurant data. like

```
{
  "id": "16774318",
  "name": "Otto Enoteca & Pizzeria",
  "url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village",
  "location": {
    "address": "1 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10003",
    "locality": "Greenwich Village",
    "city": "New York City",
    "latitude": "40.732013",
    "longitude": "-73.996155",
    "zipcode": "10003",
    "country_id": "216"
  },
  "average_cost_for_two": "60",
  "price_range": "2",
  "currency": "$",
  "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_thumb.png",
  "featured_image": "https://d.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_v2.png",
  "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/photos#tabtop",
  "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/menu#tabtop",
  "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/events#tabtop",
  "user_rating": {
    "aggregate_rating": "3.7",
    "rating_text": "Very Good",
    "rating_color": "5BA829",
    "votes": "1046"
  },
  "has_online_delivery": "0",
  "is_delivering_now": "0",
  "has_table_booking": "0",
  "deeplink": "zomato://r/16774318",
  "cuisines": "Cafe",
  "all_reviews_count": "15",
  "photo_count": "18",
  "phone_numbers": "(212) 228-2930",
  "photos": [
    {
      "id": "u_MjA5MjY1OTk5OT",
      "url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/c15/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_640_640_thumb.JPG",
      "thumb_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/c15/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_200_thumb.JPG",
      "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "zomato_handle": "John",
        "foodie_level": "Super Foodie",
        "foodie_level_num": "9",
        "foodie_color": "f58552",
        "profile_url": "https://www.zomato.com/john",
        "profile_deeplink": "zoma.to/u/1170245",
        "profile_image": "string"
      },
      "res_id": "16782899",
      "caption": "#awesome",
      "timestamp": "1435111770",
      "friendly_time": "3 months ago",
      "width": "640",
      "height": "640",
      "comments_count": "0",
      "likes_count": "0"
    }
  ],
  "all_reviews": [
    {
      "rating": "5",
      "review_text": "The best latte I've ever had. It tasted a little sweet",
      "id": "24127336",
      "rating_color": "305D02",
      "review_time_friendly": "2 months ago",
      "rating_text": "Insane!",
      "timestamp": "1435507367",
      "likes": "0",
      "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "zomato_handle": "John",
        "foodie_level": "Super Foodie",
        "foodie_level_num": "9",
        "foodie_color": "f58552",
        "profile_url": "https://www.zomato.com/john",
        "profile_deeplink": "zoma.to/u/1170245",
        "profile_image": "string"
      },
      "comments_count": "0"
    }
      ]
}
```

it gives a menu url like

https://www.zomato.com/chennai/RESTAURANT_NAME/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop

but this URL returns an entire web page ,of the restaurant's zomato menu listing's first image only .

I want the restaurant menu photos alone (all pages of the menu).
Similarly for photos too.

PS:Please don't suggest web scraping here.
Is there an API that fetches these directly?

[Zomato API guide](https://developers.zomato.com/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information, restaurant's menu photos are *not* available through the Zomato APIs. Perhaps, the listing's menu page url would be the closest option that might help in your case.

As far as the restaurant's photos are concerned, they are limited to selected API partners only. At the most, you'll be able to access the restaurant thumbnail.

See if this answers your query :)